# Unable to find the resource group (even the default one)

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I cannot find any resource groups in my own IBM Cloud account. I should have a DEFAULT resource group but I can't find it anywhere. Now, the system tells me that Watson services need to be migrated to resource groups before Oct this year. However, I cannot find any resource group that I can migrate to. I only have the option to 'create a new resource group', but I'm using the lite plan and when I try to, it says I can only have one group (but where is it???). 
I'm using Watson services in applications that are customer facing, if I'm unable to migrate, what can I do next? I cannot open a support ticket because I have no permission to do so (I also don't know why I cannot open a ticket)

Answer (score 1):

Mine are located here: https://cloud.ibm.com/account/resource-groups and it looks like this:

[image]